# Time value being removed from the datetime when I save it in MySQL

Tags: mysql, delphi, stored-procedures, ado, delphi-xe6

I'm trying to save a datetime value to a MySQL database.

```
procedure TLocalDatabaseConnectionTests.TestSaveDateTime;
var
    StoredProc : TADOStoredProc;
    Connection : TADOConnection;
    dt : TDateTime;
begin
    StoredProc := TADOStoredProc.Create(nil);
    Connection := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
    try
        Connection.LoginPrompt := false;

        Connection.ConnectionString := String.Format
        (
            'DRIVER={%s}; SERVER=%s; DATABASE=%s; UID=%s; PASSWORD=%s;OPTION=3;',
            [
                'MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver',
                'LOCALHOST',
                'DatabaseName',
                'Username',
                'Password'
            ]
        );

        StoredProc.Connection := Connection;
        StoredProc.ProcedureName := 'TestDate';

        StoredProc.Parameters.Clear;

        with StoredProc.Parameters.AddParameter do
        begin
            Name := String('@TheDate');
            DataType := TFieldType.ftDateTime;
            Direction := TParameterDirection.pdInput;
        end;

        dt := EncodeDateTime(1995, 12, 13, 13, 30, 1, 1);
        StoredProc.Parameters.ParamByName('@TheDate').DataType := TDataType.ftDateTime;
        StoredProc.Parameters.ParamByName('@TheDate').Value := TDateTime(dt);

        StoredProc.ExecProc;

    finally
        FreeAndNil(Connection);
        FreeAndNil(StoredProc);
    end;
end;
```

Here is the stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `TestDate`(TheDate DateTime)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO new_table (idnew_table)
    VALUES (TheDate);
END
```

The problem is the time always gets cut off.

[image: date]

I can't explain why this is

[image: schema]

The column is indeed defined as `DateTime` and not `Date`

Comment: Maybe I need to upgrade my Database/connector?

Comment: From the linked answer: "*You could also set the data type of the ado parameter to adDBTimeStamp yourself. **ADODB sets it to adDate when you use ftDateTime**.*"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678746/using-a-datetime-parameter-with-ado-odbc-loses-time-part indeed has the solution to this problem